# Have cleveref abbreviate to "eq. 1" just once

Tags: math-mode, cross-referencing, cleveref

I'd like to have `\cref` abbreviate to `eq. 1` just once, in a math environment. All the other `\cref`s in my document I want to spell out the full 'equation 123'. Is that possible?

As there are hundreds of references, I would also like to keep the `noabbrev` option for the rest of the document and not change all of them by hand.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref} % noabbrev!
\creflabelformat{equation}{#2\textup{#1}#3} % no (1), but 1

\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{eq:1}
    \pi=3
\end{equation}

...

\begin{equation}
    2\pi
    \stackrel{
            \text{ \cref{eq:1} } % no noabbrev here?
        }{
            =
        }
    6
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you need `\cref` if you know exactly how it should be called in that context? In that case, just use `eq.~\ref{label}`.

Comment: yup, it just came to my mind as well :D
do you by chance know how to hyperlink the whole `eq. \ref{}`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer you could locally redefine the used equation name.

Comment: @Laurenz: No need the hyperanchor.

Comment: @Skillmon: You mean `\crefname{equation}`? Thought that would be fixed somehow.

Comment: @Laurenz as far as I know, the name set by `cleveref` is not included in the hyperlink by default.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer `\bgroup\crefname{equation}{eq.}\cref{eq:1}\egroup` would work indeed.

Comment: @Skillmon: `nameinlink` option

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use `\cref` (e.g. because you want to use `nameinlink`) you could do the following (as discussed in the comments together with @ChristianHupfer):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref} % noabbrev!
\creflabelformat{equation}{#2\textup{#1}#3} % no (1), but 1

\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{eq:1}
    \pi=3
\end{equation}

...

\begin{equation}
    2\pi
    \stackrel{
      \bgroup\crefname{equation}{eq.}
      \text{ \cref{eq:1} }\egroup % no noabbrev here?
        }{
            =
        }
    6
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

A different solution not using `nameinlink` which provides hyperlinks for the full reference. I used a new command `\abcref` which places a hyperlink 
by extracting the anchor and using `\cref*` internally`.

The `\crefname{equation}{eq.}{Eq.}` is necessary anyway here.

(Note: Skillmon and I posted nearly identical solutions within the same second, so I changed my solution)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}



\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref} % noabbrev!
\creflabelformat{equation}{#2\textup{#1}#3} % no (1), but 1

\newcommand{\abcref}[1]{%
 \hyperlink{\getrefbykeydefault{#1}{anchor}{}}{\cref*{#1}}%
}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{eq:1}
    \pi=3
\end{equation}

...

\begin{equation}
    2\pi
    \stackrel{%
      \begingroup
      \crefname{equation}{eq.}{Eq.}%
      \text{ \abcref{eq:1} } % no noabbrev here?
      \endgroup
        }{
            =
        }
    6
\end{equation}

See \cref{foo} also

\begin{equation}
  E=mc^{2} \label{foo}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Now we both posted almost the exact same answer based on our comments :)

Comment: @Skillmon: You beat me by one (!!!!) second (+1 anyway!), but I have changed my solution a little bit, providing the hyperlink around the full reference locally with the `\abcref` (ab is an ab(!)breviation for ab ;-))

Comment: I really like your `\abcref` (not only for the name). Neatly done.

Comment: @Skillmon: Thanks. It would be much easier if `cleveref` would provide an optional argument for `\cref` etc. where `noabbrev` could be a local option as well...

Comment: Thought the same. It's a petty that there is no key=value syntax available to the command.

Comment: @Skillmon: If I have understood daleif correctly he is writing a package being similar to `cleveref` (in its outcome) but with `expl3` and having more configurability

Comment: I don't use `cleveref` normally, so I don't know what I'm missing, maybe I'll look into this new package.

Answer (score 2):

I can't see a good reason for using cleveref's heavy-duty machinery here. A basic `\ref` instruction does just fine.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref} 
\creflabelformat{equation}{#2\textup{#1}#3} % no surrounding parens

\newcommand\refequal[1]{\stackrel{\text{\tiny eq.\,\ref*{#1}}}{=}}
\begin{document}

\begin{gather} 
    \pi = 3         \label{eq:1}\\
    \cdots          \notag      \\
    22\pi \refequal{eq:1} 66
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```